# Issue regarding the uploading of image files in to server from android

Tags: php, android

I have created an application, using which I can upload an image stored at the gallery of my phone to the server. The server side language that I am using is PHP. The issue that I am facing is little bit strange. I am able to upload photos of size less that 2 MB, which I have taken using the camera of my phone. But certain photos are not getting uploaded. Here are the details of photos which were not getting uploaded:

**First photo:**

Title: 2013-03-15 09.17.22.jpg

Type: JPEG

Size: 2645Kb

**Second photo:**

Title: 2013-03-12 11.48.04.jpg

Type: JPEG

Size: 2781Kb

After the unsuccessful uploading of above photos I tried to upload another photo and it worked. Here are the details of the photo that I was able to upload:

Title: 2013-03-14 10.20.16.jpg

Type: JPEG

Size: 1238Kb

Then tried with few other photos less that 2000 kb and all those photos got uploaded.

Then I download a jpg image of 6 MB from net and tried to upload it. Surprisingly it got uploaded. Now I am totally confused, what the real issue is. Finally I have reached a conclusion that, the problem is only for those photos which are taken using the camera of my phone and having a size more than 2000 kb.

**Here is the android function that I am using to upload photos in to the server:**

```
public String doFileUpload(String selectedPath,String page)
        {
            String response=null;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
            String urlString = Connector.URL+page;
            try
            {
                //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Allow Outputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                // Don't use a cached copy.
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
                dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=uploadedfile;filename=" + selectedPath + "" + lineEnd);


                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                // close streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
            //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
            try 
            {
              inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
              response = inStream.readLine();
              inStream.close();

            }
            catch (IOException ioex){
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Here is the PHP code for the page that I use to upload images:

```
<?php
$tt=$_GET["id"];
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{   
    include("../../classes/Registration.php");
    $Obj=new register();
    $Obj->insert_photo_data($tt,basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']));
}
else
{
    echo '[{"flag":"0"}]';
}
?>
```

What I am getting back when the image uploading problem occurs is:

```
[{"flag":"0"}]
```

Comment: try using a bitmap to compress the size of the pic that will eventually be uploaded. Not a lot of use in uploading the full size of mobile images. any service like google plus is going to compress before putting the stream on the network for the upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue was related to wamp. I have opened php.ini and changed the line

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

to

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Now images are getting uploaded without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change.   dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);    to    dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead).    What reaches the server if a picture is not uploaded?